# How to import python files into main.py on repl.it?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, replit

**Straight to the point:**

I have created three files on **repl.it** along with my main.py -
*Logger.py, Responses.py,* and *phrases.json*

Now when I am trying to import them into main.py using,

```
import Logger.py
import Response.py
import phrases.json
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import Logger.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Logger.py'; 'Logger' is not a package
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import a python file from your current folder, you just need the name without extension.

```py
import Logger  # this is ./Logger.py
import Response  # this is ./Response.py
```

For the JSON, you can't import these directly as they aren't python files. Python does have a standard library to read JSON:

```py
import json

with open("phrases.json") as f:
    phrases = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Same problem, brother. 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Response.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Logger.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Logger.py'; 'Logger' is not a package`

Comment: Again, you're attempting to import `Logger.py`. You have to remove the extension so that it's just `import Logger`. Every file that has this mistake must be fixed as well. I think the mistake is in `Response.py`.

Comment: No sir I didn't. Whats the point of lying to you. I wrote only Logger.
`# custom libraries
import Logger
import Response
#os.system("python Logger.py")

#os.system("python Response.py")`

Comment: Either way, whatever you just commented isn't the solution I suggested but rather @Harjuuso. I recommend you update your question with the first few lines of each file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve.. Could you possibly attach your files here? First thing what im thinking of is, you could import/run the other files inside your `main.py`:

```
import os
os.system("python ~file~.py")
```

And of course replace ~file~ with your file ;)

Comment: following your instruction, I still have the problem

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Response.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Logger.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Logger.py'; 'Logger' is not a package`

Comment: Sorry i did a mistake on my part in Response.py
Sorry for the inconvenience